# Show that $\Bbb Z_{16}$ is not a homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Show that $\Bbb Z_{16}$ is not a homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4$.

My solution goes like this:

> We consider $f$ as an epimorphism. Now, $f:\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4\longrightarrow \Bbb Z_{16}$. Hence, $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4/Kerf\cong \Bbb Z_{16}$. So, $\frac{|\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4|}{|Kerf|}=|\Bbb{Z}_{16}|$. This means $Kerf=1$, and so, $f$ is an isomorphism,  so $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4\cong \Bbb Z_{16}$. Now, $\Bbb Z_{16}$ is cyclic, while $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4$, is not. So, they are not isomorphic,  hence, contradiction.

Is this a correct argument? Is the proof correct?

Comment: Hint: Consider the order of the elements.

Comment: This means $Kerf=1$, and so, $f$ is an isomorphism,  so $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4\cong \Bbb Z_{16}$. Now, $\Bbb Z_{16}$ is cyclic, while $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4$, is not. So, they are not isomorphic,  hence, contradiction. Is this a correct argument?

Comment: Yes, it is a correct argument:)

Comment: @Nik But I used the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @Franklin No your question is fine. I missed the word epimorphism (which by definition is onto) in your question.

Comment: @ALNS Thanks, I get it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively (without the homomorphism theorem), let $f\colon G\to H$ be a homomorpism of finite groups. Then, for every $x\in G$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
e_H=f(e_G)=f(x^{o(x)}) &= f(x)^{o(x)}
\end{alignat}
and hence:
$$o(f(x))\mid o(x)\tag1$$

In your setting, if $f$ is surjective, then an element of order $16$ of $\Bbb Z_{16}$ is the image of some $x\in\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_4$, whose order is less than $16$ (because the elements of this group have maximal order $4$). But this contradicts $(1)$. Therefore, there isn't any such a surjective homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is not a contradiction yet, but you can continue arguing to obtain one. What does this last equation tell you about $|\mathrm{Ker}(f)|$? What does that tell you about $f$? Can you derive a contradiction from there?

Comment: This means $Kerf=1$, and so, $f$ is an isomorphism,  so $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4\cong \Bbb Z_{16}$. But then?

Comment: Can we argue like this:$\Bbb Z_{16}$ is cyclic, while $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4$, is not. So, they are not isomorphic,  hence, contradiction?

Comment: @Franklin, yes, for example, that will work.